# Posting AJAX string to MVC Controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post a string (the name of the href the user clicked on) using AJAX to my MVC controller (which it will then use to filter my table results according to the string).

Whilst I have managed to get it to post (at-least according to the alerts) on the AJAX side, it doesn't seem to arrive properly on the controller side and is seen as null in my quick error capture (the if statement).

Please excuse the useless naming conventions for the moment. I've been going through countless methods to try and fix this, so will name properly when I've got a proper solution :).

I've been at work for this for a long while now and can't seem to solve the conundrum so any help is appreciated please! I'm very new to AJAX and MVC in general so I'm hoping it's a minor mistake. :) (FYI I have tried both post and get and both seem to yield the same result?)

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetSafeItems(string yarp)
    {
        using (CBREntities2 dc = new CBREntities2())
        {
            if (yarp == null)
            {
                ViewBag.safeselected = yarp;
            }
            var safeItem = dc.Items.Where(a => a.Safe_ID == yarp).Select(s => new {
                Serial_Number = s.Serial_Number,
                Safe_ID = s.Safe_ID,
                Date_of_Entry = s.Date_of_Entry,
                Title_subject = s.Title_subject,
                Document_Type = s.Document_Type,
                Sender_of_Originator = s.Sender_of_Originator,
                Reference_Number = s.Reference_Number,
                Protective_Marking = s.Protective_Marking,
                Number_recieved_produced = s.Number_recieved_produced,
                copy_number = s.copy_number,
                Status = s.Status,
                Same_day_Loan = s.Same_day_Loan
            }).ToList();

        //    var safeItems = dc.Items.Where(a => a.Safe_ID).Select(s => new { Safe_ID = s.Safe_ID, Department_ID = s.Department_ID, User_ID = s.User_ID }).ToList();
            return Json(new { data = safeItem }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

AJAX function (on View page):

```
$('.tablecontainer').on('click', 'a.safeLink', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var yarp = $(this).attr('safesel');
            var selectedSafeZZ = JSON.stringify("SEC-1000");
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/GetSafeItems',
                data: { 'yarp': JSON.stringify(yarp) },
                type: "GET",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(yarp);
                    console.log("We WIN " + data)
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert("Boohooo");
                }
            });

        })
```

** The Alert reveals the correct type: "SEC-1000" 
But the console Log shows: WE WIN [Object object]??

Comment: Try `console.log("We WIN " + JSON.stringify(data))` - it's an object

Comment: Hi Steve, that returns the following result instead: We WIN {"data":[]} ... Im guessing this is showing that DATA is empty but yarp is fine??

Comment: Yeah, [] is an empty array - so nothing has been returned. If it's an array, you can do `if(data.length > 0) { ...` then a for each for each element.

Comment: It SHOULD just be posting a single string "SEC-1000" for my Controller method to pickup and use. So not sure why it's coming out as an array?

Comment: Once thing you are doing wrong is `data: { 'yarp': JSON.stringify(yarp) },` - yarp is a string (not a JSON object). Also you getting a `List()` of whatever for `safeItem` and sending it back so this is correct - it is an array.

Comment: I have tried         data: yarp,          on it's own too... but get the same problem?

Comment: This AJAX statement is on the Homepage, but with regards to SafeItem ahhh... that SHOULD be returning the filtered results to my now redirected to "Safe page" If that makes any sense?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your backend function putting a breakpoint to be sure that your safeItem variable is populated ?

Comment: There I think lies my issue. the return safeItem is meant for another page, but I need YARP to help filter the results before I get to that page. So how would be best to solve that? (I hope Im making sense... It's all very confusing me atm!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried something basic in a new mvc dummy project :

View page basic textbox and a button :

```
<input type="text" id="txt_test" value="test"/>
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="test()">Test</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function test()
        {
            var text = $("#txt_test")[0].value;

            $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.RouteUrl(new{ action="GetSafeItems", controller="Home"})',
            // edit 
            // data: {yarp: JSON.stringify(text)},
            data: {yarp: text},
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {
                // edit 
                // alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                alert(data.data);
            }});
        }           
</script>
```

Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetSafeItems(string yarp)
{
        return Json(new {data = string.Format("Back end return : {0}",yarp)}
        , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Alert result => {"data":"Back end return : \"test\""}

It's a simple ajax call to a web method. You don't return a view, so I don't understand the use of

```
if (yarp == null)
{
    ViewBag.safeselected = yarp;
}
```

Also I see an [Authorize] attribute, you perhaps use some authentication and I don't see any authentication header on your ajax call

Comment: That's honestly fantastic thankyou!! It has now got it posting to the server and I have a similar alert result to yours.. though instead of text box, mine comes from a sort of href so I have used : var text = $(this).attr('safesel'); but still works the same... HOWEVER, is there a way of trimming the data down to only the actual text? For example... my input is "SEC-1000" but the data is sent as {"data":"\"SEC-1000\""} which means it bypasses my controller if statement for not technically being "SEC-1000".

Comment: As for the final point, that if statement is just waste code that allows me to put a troubleshoot point in so yes that won't be there once this is solved. and as for the Authorize, it is part of the ASP.NET MVC security so shouldn't cause any issue with this to my knowledge :)

Comment: Actually since you only deal with text you can get rid of the JSON.stringify transformations : data: {yarp: JSON.stringify(text)} => data: {yarp: text} and in the success callback : alert(JSON.stringify(data)); => alert(data.data);

Comment: Honestly, you are an absolute life saver!! THANKYOU! It all works how it should do now and I can continue onwards! As I said, very new to this and have to work on it as part of a project so very thankful for the assist... I can now relax a little bit more!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.each(data, function (i) { console.log("We WIN " + data[i].Serial_Number )});
```